# kafka not able to connect to remote server

Tags: grails, apache-kafka

I'am trying to connect to a remote kafka server. My application is running in one instance and kafka is running in the other instance. I thought it is a very 
 straight forward one. But seems it is not working. When I run kafka locally everything works fine. I'am using grails .Can anyone help me with this. Any help would be appreciated.

This is my kafka config.

kafka:

```
config:
    bootstrapServers: ip_where_my_kafka_is_running:9092
    acks: all
    retries: 0
    batchSize: 16384
    lingerMs: 1
    bufferMemory: 33554432
    keySerializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
    valueSerializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
```

Comment: Is the remote server rejecting the connection from your application? Any error logs or source code you might have would be useful.

Comment: There is no logs on the kafka.... Unfortunately even from the application side they are not throwing any exception. I'am not sure whether the configuration has any problem or the in the kafka server's properties do i need to change something.

Comment: Can you `telnet` to port 9092 of the broker from your client machine?

Comment: Error log please .

Answer (score 1):

Kafka takes values like `bootstrap.servers` , `key.serializer` ,`value.serializer` , `buffer.memory`, `batch.size` so try to use like this.

Comment: True that is....But in grails we can use in the above way....i don't see any issue with the keys.